# hashing json keys before rendering a jbuilder template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I'm looking for a way to control the a step or few steps before a json is rendered when I execute `x = render template: "temp1" format: :json` (I have `temp1.jbuilder` in my views). I want to encode the keys of the json with base64 before creating a json string. Right now I do it only after the json string is rendered and it means I get a string, parse it to json using `JSON.parse`, encode the keys, and convert to json string again using `.to_json`

Would be nice to control somehow which jbuilder templates will get this behavior and which will not. What I have in my mind is something like: `render template: "temp1", format: :json, encode: true`